# Visio VBA - line connected to a callout

Tags: vba, visio

I have a callout touching a line in Visio 2013.

I've noticed:

1. I can't see it in GluedShapes
2. I can't add connector points to the line (which I think triggers GluedShapes)

Here is the code I'm using to find it.

```
 For Each shp In Visio.ActivePage.Shapes
     conn = shp.Name
     aryTargetIDs = shp.GluedShapes(visGluedShapesAll1D, "")
     For i = 0 To UBound(aryTargetIDs)
         Set targetShape = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(aryTargetIDs(i))
         Tgt = targetShape.Text
         Debug.Print "1D glue " & conn & "|" & Tgt
     Next i 
 Next shp
```

[image: and the drawing]

Any ideas how to find the "connection"? Perhaps trying to iterate through anything that travels under the callout's end..

Answer (score 0):

ok, I feel this is a bit clunky but it seems the way to do it..
Basically cribbing from [SpatialRelationship property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ms367944(v=office.12)) and working from the selected shape/s

here is my code

```
Dim intTolerance As Integer
Dim intReturnValue As VisSpatialRelationCodes
Dim intFlag As VisSpatialRelationFlags
Dim strReturn As String
    
Set sel = ActiveWindow.Selection
For Each shp In sel
    conn = shp.Name
    'Initialize tolerance argument.
    intTolerance = 0.25

    'Initialize flags argument.
    intFlag = visSpatialIncludeHidden
    For Each vsoShapeOnPage In ActivePage.Shapes
    
        'Get the spatial relationship.
        intReturnValue = shp.SpatialRelation(vsoShapeOnPage, _
            intTolerance, intFlag)
    
        'Convert return code to string value.
        Select Case intReturnValue
            Case VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialContain
                'strReturn = "Contains"
            Case VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialContainedIn
                'strReturn = "is Contained in"
            Case VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialOverlap
                'strReturn = "overlaps"
            Case VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialTouching
                strReturn = "is touching"
            Case Else
                'strReturn = "has no relation with"
        End Select
       
        'Display relationship in the shape's text.
        vsoShapeOnPage.Text = shp.Name & " " & strReturn & " " & vsoShapeOnPage.Name
    
    Next
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: Note intTolerance is quite important... 0.25 will pick up "snap to geometry" but not "snap to vertex" changing it to 1.0 will pick up vertex, but will also pickup shapes not touching...